# OpenMesh copy all standard and custom properties from one mesh element to another

Tags: openmesh

OpenMesh offers the possibility to store properties on mesh elements (faces, vertices, half edges, edges) as described [here](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a04346.html). Is there a function available which copies all of these properties from one element to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [copy_all_properties](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a02133.html#ab1b8cb02dfc4544f2762de962a2ce7ad).

Signature (comes in few flavors- VertexHandle, HalfedgeHandle, EdgeHandle and FaceHandle):

```
void OpenMesh::BaseKernel::copy_all_properties(EdgeHandle _eh_from, EdgeHandle  _eh_to, bool _copyBuildIn = false )
```

Usage example from git repo: [unittests_property.cc](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de:9000/OpenMesh/OpenMesh/-/blob/master/src/Unittests/unittests_property.cc)

Comment: is it possible to use `copy_all_properties` to copy properties of elements that belong to different meshes, given that the same property exists on the elements of the other mesh?

Comment: No. Link to your new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538092/openmesh-copy-all-properties-between-elements-belonging-to-different-meshes (as reference for future readers)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I added a minimal example to my new question to show it does not work.